# How to enable POST env management endpoint with Spring boot 3.x and Spring WebFlux?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

How to enable POST env management endpoint with Spring boot 3.x and Spring WebFlux?

This was working fine with Spring Boot 2.7.x and is no more working with Spring Boot 3.x.

Activating the debug mode (debug: true) I can't find any trace of `WritableEnvironmentEndpointAutoConfiguration`.

Here is the relevant part of my application.yml.

```
management:
  endpoints:
    enabled-by-default: true
    web:
      exposure:
        include: '*'
  endpoint:
    env:
      post:
        enabled: true
      enabled: true
    health:
      probes:
        enabled: true
      show-details: always
```

Answer (score 0):

The current latest version of spring-cloud-dependencies is not compatible with Spring Boot 3.X.

It is necessary to migrate to a newer version to make it work.

At the time of writing I used the following combination which was working:

```
implementation(platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:3.0.0"))
implementation(platform("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2022.0.0"))
```